# Repeat (crop) texture at the edge of the UV island

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm not quite sure I'm asking the right question, but here's my problem: I have this tile texture, but it contains a very high tile which I would like to get rid of:

[image: screenshot]

I have highlighted in red the part that I'd like to get rid of.

However, even with the UV island scaled smaller than the texture, the whole texture is used:

[image: screenshot]

Again highlighted the parts I would like to get rid of.

Node setup:

[image: screenshot]

Object properties:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check if the material uses UV as map, the scale of the texture is 1,1,1, and if the mesh has more than one UV map. If the material uses the UV map you are showing in the picture, everything will work as expected. If this doesn't solve the problem show us your material nodes and the vertices properties panel.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Edited in the info. Honestly, it makes sense that it doesn't work out of the box. When I load a repeatable texture, most of the time I want to use the whole image. And how would Blender know how to crop the image, especially when the island is irregularly shaped.

Comment: The *Mapping* node has the scale set to (3.0, 3.0, 3.0) change it to (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) and it should match your UV layout exactly.

Comment: @rjg But then it's not repeated at all.

Comment: The Mapping node's scale will repeat the texture, not the UV. So just imagine you create a 3 times bigger image in a picture editor and tile the texture 3 times. It will result a picture with the 3 red lines at the thirds. So you can't solve this problem this way. So what you can do is subdivide the face of the mesh and folding the UVMap on the edges. But in this way you can't resize the texture afterwards with the mapping node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar, trying to use one tiled texture for the whole model but still keep the tiling ability. Looks like yours just needs to change the mapping scale to 1 across the board and you'll be set.
[image: Functional Cropped/Tileable UV Map]